# Aggregation on countinues status in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hive

I am dealing with some log data with playing status that comprises `play` and `end`. During a game, client will report `play` multi-times but when `end` appears, it means a game ends, like

```
user_id  status  timestamp
   a      play    xxx
   a      play    xxx
   a      play    xxx
   a      end     xxx
   b      play    xxx
   b      end     xxx
   c      play    xxx
   c      play    xxx
   c      end     xxx
   a      play    xxx
   a      play    xxx
   a      end     xxx
   a      play    xxx
   a      end     xxx
```

Now, I can use `row_number()` to calculate the number of `user_id` with games of more than 2 `play` status like:

```
# I realize this is a wrong query...

select count(distinct user_id) as cnt_uid
    (select  
        user_id,status,timestamp, 
        row_number() over (partition by user_id, status, order by timestamp) as rn
    from tableA) a
    where rn>=2
```

But if I need to calculate the number of games with more than 2 `play` status (e.g.: `user A` has 2 games with over 2 `play` status and `user C` has 1), how to do this?   Any help is appreciated.

*PS: The expected result is just a number of games with more than 2 `play` status and for the data given above, the result is `3`.

Comment: You can use DENSE_RANK() if available in hive

Comment: @DigvijayS Thanks for your reply. I tried `dense_rank() over (order by status)` in `Hive `and I think the result is equivlent to `user_id`...  Feel free to let me know if I did not use it in a proper way....

Comment: Can you please add expected output by editing your post.

Comment: Hi @DigvijayS I just modified the post and actually, the expected output in this case is just a number: `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the "games" using a cumulative sum of `status = 'end'`.  Then aggregate and aggregate again:

```
select user_id, count(*) as games_with_2+_plays
from (select user_id, grp, count(*) as num_plays
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(case when status = 'end' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by timestamp) as grp
            from t
           ) t
      where status = 'play'
      group by user_id, grp
     )
where num_plays >= 2
group by user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your brilliant answer!!! In your query `status = 'end'` is removed, this works. If I need time interval of each game  (time interval = timestamp of `end` - timestamp of the firstl `play` of each game), how to calculate this?

Comment: @user2894829 . . . You would do something like the difference between `min(timestamp)` and `max(timestamp)`.